# Spark XML parsing

Tags: xml, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to parse a large XML file using `com.databricks.spark.xml`

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
            .option("rowTag", "row").load("../1000.xml");

df.show(10);
```

The output I get is as follows

> ++ ||
>   ++
>   ++

am I missing something?

this is my sample XML row.

```
<row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4" CreationDate="2008-07-31T22:17:57.883" Score="316" Body="&lt;p&gt;An explicit cast to double isn't necessary.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;double trans = (double)trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Identifying the constant as &lt;code&gt;5000.0&lt;/code&gt; (or as &lt;code&gt;5000d&lt;/code&gt;) is sufficient:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;&#xA;double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000d;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;" />
```

many thanks.

Comment: It means your the data in xml didn't mapped to columnar structure and your dataset is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `_` symbol before an XML attribute name in your schema. If it is not working - try to use `@` symbol. Watch [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NemEp53yGbI&t=1935s), but it is provided for old Spark version.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your xml data. Try it out as example xml data:

```
<row id="7">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology
      society in England, the young survivors lay the
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </row>
```

with your code sample:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
            .option("rowTag", "row").load("../1000.xml");
```

To provide custom schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType};

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("_id", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("author", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("description", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("genre", StringType ,nullable = true),
    StructField("price", DoubleType, nullable = true),
    StructField("publish_date", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("title", StringType, nullable = true)))


val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("books.xml")

val selectedData = df.select("author", "_id")
selectedData.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag", "books")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .save("newbooks.xml")
```

Please refer to [databricks xml documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)

Comment: isn't there a way to pass XML attributes in spark.xml. If I'm creating a custom schema how to create one to pass XML attributes?

Comment: Hi FaigB thanks for the answer, I too read through the databricks documentation but I can't figure out a way to pass attributes of XML tags. Because I can't change the XML format as you mentioned.